# Would Dark Heresy or Only War work better for a primarily story-driven campaign?

Tags: game-recommendation, warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-1e, only-war

I have only played Dungeons and Dragons RPG so far but I have always been a big fan of the Warhammer 40k universe. I was wondering whether  Dark Heresy II or Only war are better for my group? The group I typically play with is not extremely serious so I am looking for an RPG that is more oriented towards story and narrative and less towards clunky and complex mechanics and combat.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Unlike on traditional Internet forums, game recommendation questions need to follow [some guidelines](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071) to avoid purely opinion-based answers. Can you please edit your question to tell us what you're looking for in a Warhammer RPG? Information about the kind of RPG stories you hope to tell, the sorts of characters your group will want to play, and so forth, will let us give you answers that are tailored to your situation.

Comment: It is impossible to recommend one of those over the other, as they provide entirely different experiences. While they both take place in the same setting, they are completely different on a fundamental level in what they attempt to accomplish. Only War is a system made for War Stories, with characters getting killed left, right, and center. Dark Heresy is a game about intrigue and rooting out heresy. It does have combat, and you will most likely kill someone, but it is much more about finding out who the heretics actually are. We need more parameters to suggest a best system for your group.

Comment: In other words, please explain more about what you want out of the game and then we can meaningfully recommend one.  Please improve this question, not open new duplicates.

Comment: The asker's focus on "story and narrative" over combat pretty much makes this question's a foregone conclusion to people familiar with the games.  Xanderh's comment is basically already an answer.  This question should be reopened and answered.  (Although I feel a frame-challenge is in order, too - I think the OP would be best served using a different system entirely - maybe FAE or Fate Core - and just using the WH40K setting.)